In Euclidean Geometry how is "beyond" defined on a plane?
I am trying to do a construction on a plane. The beginning of the problem states "Let there be two lines and a point beyond them." I felt like I was making pretty good progress but when I went over the work to check for false assumptions, I came across the word "beyond".  Is there a precise definition for the word beyond when used in this context?
The issue is if my two lines are intersecting, is there a restriction to where the point can be placed? Can the point be in the interior of angle 1?Intersecting Lines
Original Problem:
Let there be two lines (e1) and (e2) and a point A beyond them. Both lines and the point A are on the same plane. How can we construct a line (x1) starting from A which intersects the line (e1) on point B and the line (e2) on point D and similarly a line (x2) starting from A which intersects the line (e1) on point C and the line (e2) on point E so that BC=a and DE=b, where the lengths a, b are given.

I'm guessing it means a point not on either line? Without the full statement or access to the original text or document, it's hard to know with absolute certainty however.

It’s odd phrasing. Perhaps if you give us the full problem text we could help more.

I have added the original problem. Thank you for taking the time to help. @CameronWilliams

It just means not on the lines

There are other oddities in the way the problem is stated - such as using "starting from" instead of "passing through" to indicate $A$ should be on the lines. But surely RobinSparrow is correct - there isn't any information given that would support any meaning other than "does not lie on".
